# uwp c# 2019: How to refer to RootGrid

Tags: c#, namespaces, uwp-xaml, code-behind

Sorry.  I think I've found it.

I thought the suggestion reference to "RootGrid" was to a VS Named Space, like   System.Windows.RootGrid  I'm relatively sure they intended me to refer to a Grid in my XAML.

Realizing this probability was a "DUH" moment. So, just replacing RootGrid with my XAML name "GridBoard" will probably solve the issue.   I haven't got the close of the Control to work yet, but he naming issue is at least being found.

To answer the question.  Help, is a User control file in ScqWander Program.  localUCHelp was the name used to create an instance on the Page.

---

Quick overview: How do I refer to RootGrid?

I get RootGrid  **"Does not exist in current context"**

I am using VS 2019 and have a C# project, using XAML.  I wrote a UserControl and am trying code a Button to Close the control (when clicked work from within the control). I got a suggestion which included the sample below. Google has turned up nothing.
The code is within the namespace

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
```

```
void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 ScqWander.Help localUCHelp = new ScqWander.Help();
 localUCHelp.HelpUserControlCloseEvent += new EventHandler(BtnPXClose);
 RootGrid.Chilren.Add(localUCHelp);
}
```

Comment: What is your `ScqWander.Help`? Is this a Button you coded? From the above code, do you want to add localUCHelp to a panel in XAML? Have you added a panel named RootGrid in your MainPage.xaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was simply thinking that "RootGrid" reference to which I could refer (as in Using System.Whateverxxxx) when I should have been referring to the Grid I defined in my XAML.  I just did not recognize what was being said in the example.